# Vista won't boot. BSOD: Page fault in nonpaged area

Tags: windows-vista, boot, bsod

Here's the story: I let Windows Update do the updates it wanted to do, then rebooted the computer. The updating process was taking time so I went away. When I came back, my computer was rebooting. It got as far as the Windows logo with the laoding bar. BSOD'd. Rebooted.

And I'm stuck in this loop ever since.
Looked up on the net, the "Page fault in nonpaged area" seems to be linked to faulty RAM or drivers.

So I ran a memory test, it found no error.

When I try in safe mode (with promt) I can see a list of drivers being loaded, then I get the same BSOD.

I tried to repair using the Vista DVD, it says "nothing to repair".

I tried to restore to a previous state, it says "no restore point found".

So, my guess is, it's got something to do with the drivers. How can I identify the one causing the BSOD? If you have any other leads, What can I do?

By the way, I'm writing from this very computer, running a linux distro I installed after the BSOD loop started. So i guess it's not an hardware issue. I have backed up important data, and will format and reinstall Windows if I must. But I'd like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some mysterious BSODs related to a broken hard disk. You might want to run CHKDSK from the installation disk:

```
CHKDSK c:/r
```

In the end this didn't work out for me, because the system disk was damaged beyond repair.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, it found a couple errors and fixed them, but the BSOD is still there.